# Where clause with Zend_Db not working as expected

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, zend-db

I am getting an error:
**Message:** `SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%'Chinese'%) ORDER BY`text_id`DESC LIMIT 10' at line 2`

caused by this line of code

```
 $select = $this->_db->select('')
            ->from(array('t'=>'as_text'))
           ->where('`s`.`name` LIKE %?%',$search) //this is causing error
            ->limit((int)$limit)
            ->order('text_id DESC')
            ->join(array('s'=>'as_source'),'t.source_id = s.source_id',array('s.name as source'));
```

My target is this sql:

```
SELECT `t` . * , `s`.`name` AS `source`
FROM `as_text` AS `t`
INNER JOIN `as_source` AS `s` ON t.source_id = s.source_id
WHERE `s`.`name` LIKE '%Chinese%'
ORDER BY `text_id` DESC
LIMIT 10
```

i think it's the  ->where bit, because when I remove it i get 10 rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: 
This works for me:

```
        ->from(array('t'=>'as_text')) 
       ->where("s.name LIKE ?",'%'.$search.'%') //this is causing error 
        ->limit((int)$limit) 
        ->order('text_id DESC') 
        ->join(array('s'=>'as_source'),
        't.source_id = s.source_id',
        array('s.name as source'));
```

Let me know if that works.

Comment: no i didn't, but after doing it still get error `SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%'Chinese'%) ORDER BY `text_id` DESC LIMIT 10' at line 2 `

Comment: I tried it, and it generates a funtional query that way. The problem was the the WHERE clause should end up looking like this: WHERE s.name LIKE '%blah%'